# AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'read_csv' の対処法

Tags: python, pandas, anaconda

以下のコードでcsvを読み込もうとしたら、題名の通りエラーが出てしまいます。

**実行したコード**

```
import pandas as pd
x = pd.read_csv("wine-R.csv")
```

**エラーメッセージ**

```
AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'read_csv'
```

確認したこと：
・カレントディレクトリ内にpandas.pyといったファイルはない。
・`print(pandas)` とすると `module "pandas" (namespace)` となる。

環境としては、Anaconda経由でjupyter notebookを使っており、OSはmacです。
対処法がわかる方がいらっしゃいましたらよろしくお願いします。

Comment: どのパスから pandas module を読み込んだのかを知りたいので、`import os` としてから `os.path.abspath(pd.__file__)` を実行して、その結果を教えて下さい。

Comment: 今日確認したところよくわかりませんが解決していました。ありがとうございます。